# Docker - Tomcat and PostgreSQL containers in same host - No Route to host

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, containers, docker

I have containerized a web application running on Tomcat and started the container using the command,

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 tveuser/tve-repository:tve-services
```

I am also running a PostgreSQL container on the same host using the following command:

```
docker run -d  -p 80:80 -p  5432:5432 tveuser/tve-repository:tve-postgresql
```

i verified that the PostgreSQL is running by using phpPgAdmin but could not get tomcat to connect to it. 'docker ps' also tells me that both the containers are up and running.

I connect the web application with the database through tomcat context.xml which has an entry like

```
<Parameter name="abc.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://1.2.3.4:5432/dbname" />
```

where 1.2.3.4 is the docker host Ip in which the container is running.But i get the following error when i run the tomcat container:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:225)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
...............

Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** : check the firewall on your host

You need to connect to your host's IP address on the port that you've exposed for postgres on your postgres container, not to the IP address of the docker container.

E.g.,

```
<Parameter name="abc.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.x.x:5432/dbname" />
```

You'll also need to configure postgres inside your postgres docker container to listen for connections from somewhere other than `127.0.0.1`, which is the default.

E.g., in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

This tells postgres to accept incoming connections from any IP address (you'll probably want to lock this down to something like `192.168.0.0/16`.

You'll also need to change the value of `listen_addresses` in `postgres.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Once you've made these configuration changes, you can check to see if postgres is listening to all requests from all IPs inside your docker container:

```
netstat -tunlp

Active Internet connections (only servers)                                 
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      816/postgres         
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      816/postgres
```

And then from your host, make sure you can telnet into port 5432:

```
telnet 192.168.x.x 5432
Trying 192.168.x.x...
Connected to 192.168.x.x.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: Telnet from tomcat container to postgresql container does not work. It says No route to host. Not sure why. I am doing telnet with the host IP(in which postgresql container is deployed) and the port of the postgresql(5432)

Comment: OK, update your question above and give me the output of: `netstat -tunlp` on a) your host and b) your postgres container. And also add your `pg_hba.conf` and `postgres.conf` files.

Comment: OK will update. But when i run telnet command from my tomcat container, telnet 1.2.3.4 5432, where 1.2.3.4 is the host IP in which the postgresql container is deployed and running and 5432, its exposed port number, it says no route to host. Its not intended right ?

Comment: No, you should be able to telnet from your tomcat container into your postgres container using your host IP and 5432.

Comment: One more thing, does your host machine have `iptable` rules? If yes, you'll need to allow connections from the `docker0` interface.

Comment: Spot on. The problem was the IPTables. I should have figured that out earlier. Now it works. Thanks for your response

Comment: @KarthikJ, can you please explain what you have done on your IPTables?

Comment: Something like `-A INPUT -i docker0 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Yes. You can also check by "/etc/init.d/iptables save" and "chkconfig iptables off" commands to check whether the firewall rules is the culprit and then enable them again using the command "/etc/init.d/iptables start"

Answer (score 0):

As Chris McKinnel points out, forwarding ports to the host doesn't work like that.  I wanted to give you a second solution as an alternative to his:  Links.

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

So you could do something like:

docker run -d -P --name tomcat --link postgres:postgres apache/tomcat apachectl start

... which, assuming your PostgreSQL container was named "postgres", would allow you to connect directly from the Tomcat container.

Note that this only works if both containers are on the same machine, but it sounds like they are.

Comment: But port forwarding across hosts works out of the box in docker. The problem was the firewall rules of the host machine.